# Cargo build results in "No match for id"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm unable to build with cargo today due to a "no match for id" error.

What's going on here?

```
$ rustup default stable
info: using existing install for 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin'
info: default toolchain set to 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin'

  stable-x86_64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)

$ git clone https://github.com/serde-rs/json
Cloning into 'json'...
remote: Counting objects: 1755, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
remote: Total 1755 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1729
Receiving objects: 100% (1755/1755), 401.86 KiB | 431.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (717/717), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ cd json/json
$ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
error: failed to load source for a dependency on `clippy`

Caused by:
  Unable to update registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index

Caused by:
  failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  [9/-3] Object not found - no match for id (aaceb5b4ca9ce0a6e5a02f86cea5635f721d29d8)
```

Comment: Works for me. Appears to be a transient network error.

Comment: It's not a network issue. Something was dodgy in my ~/.cargo/registry

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused the problem - but can attest that it was not a network issue. Removing `~/.cargo/registry` fixed the issue.

```
$ mv ~/.cargo/registry/ ~/.cargo/registry_
$ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
 Downloading num-traits v0.1.36
 Downloading serde v0.8.19
 Downloading dtoa v0.2.2
 Downloading itoa v0.1.1
   Compiling itoa v0.1.1
   Compiling dtoa v0.2.2
   Compiling num-traits v0.1.36
   Compiling serde v0.8.19
     Running `rustc /Users/jem/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/itoa-0.1.1/src/lib.rs --crate-name itoa --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=58ab3e11c7b36cd3 -C extra-filename=-58ab3e11c7b36cd3 --out-dir /Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc /Users/jem/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dtoa-0.2.2/src/lib.rs --crate-name dtoa --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=76ebb504ac31c05f -C extra-filename=-76ebb504ac31c05f --out-dir /Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc /Users/jem/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/num-traits-0.1.36/src/lib.rs --crate-name num_traits --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=92bb90166cd1857c -C extra-filename=-92bb90166cd1857c --out-dir /Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --cap-lints allow`
     Running `rustc /Users/jem/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-0.8.19/src/lib.rs --crate-name serde --crate-type lib -g --cfg feature=\"default\" --cfg feature=\"std\" -C metadata=97f01bf227222121 -C extra-filename=-97f01bf227222121 --out-dir /Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --cap-lints allow`
   Compiling serde_json v0.8.4 (file:///Users/jem/t/json/json)
     Running `rustc src/lib.rs --crate-name serde_json --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=924ef2e3fa7e5748 --out-dir /Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps --extern num_traits=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps/libnum_traits-92bb90166cd1857c.rlib --extern serde=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps/libserde-97f01bf227222121.rlib --extern dtoa=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps/libdtoa-76ebb504ac31c05f.rlib --extern itoa=/Users/jem/t/json/json/target/debug/deps/libitoa-58ab3e11c7b36cd3.rlib`
    Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 8.44 secs
```

Comment: Just ran into this same issue after switching from installing rust via the universal binaries to using rustup. This seems to have fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting the same issue.

`rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry`

Clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

This can ALSO happen if Cargo.lock is referencing a git commit ID that no longer exists. Remove Cargo.lock to fix it.